# In win32 C++ programming how can I duplicate a window style?

Tags: c++, winapi

Let's say I've a `HWND` of a Window in win32 c++ programming. How can I create another window with exactly the same styles programmatically? I know I'll have to use `CreateWindowEx` but how do I find all the parameters of the existing window to pass to `CreateWindowEx`?

Answer (score 6):

[GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should retrieve what you need from the original window.  It returns a [WINDOWINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure with the following:

```
typedef struct tagWINDOWINFO {
  DWORD cbSize;
  RECT  rcWindow;
  RECT  rcClient;
  DWORD dwStyle;
  DWORD dwExStyle;
  DWORD dwWindowStatus;
  UINT  cxWindowBorders;
  UINT  cyWindowBorders;
  ATOM  atomWindowType;
  WORD  wCreatorVersion;
} WINDOWINFO, *PWINDOWINFO, *LPWINDOWINFO;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DWORD existingStyle = (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
DWORD existingExStyle = (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
```

This gets the existing styles (`dwStyle` parameter to `CreateWindowEx`) and extended styles (`dwExStyle` parameter `CreateWindowEx`).

Note also that you should pretty much not call `GetWindowLong` directly. Although in this case it's harmless it's not a good habit to get into, because it doesn't work with pointers on 64-bit Windows. `GetWindowLongPtr` is documented as what you should call instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GetWindowLong()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to query both the GWL_STYLE and GWL_EXSTYLE flags.

Comment: @Chris: GetWindowLong works 100% in 64bit apps, if you dont retrieve handle or pointer, so your comment is stupidity. Please teach something before posting.

Comment: @Xearinox, I said function, not use of the function. Are you honestly suggesting to use this whenever it'll work and the `Ptr` version when it won't rather than one that always works without so much as a note?

Comment: For retrieving GWL_STYLE is GetWindowLong 100% legitimate.

Comment: @Xearinox - The point is that if you use `GetWindowLong` you are creating more work and potential bugs for yourself by having to remember whether it's ok to use this function or the other one. However, `GetWindowLongPtr` works for *both* `GWL_STYLE` and things like `GWLP_WNDPROC`. Since that is the case, why not just always use `GetWindowLongPtr` and save yourself the bother?

Comment: Yeah, this is true and I agree, but HerJoebob answer is valid from my point of view.